# Clonezilla clone to smaller drive

Tags: clonezilla

I've got a 285GB drive that I want to clone to a 256GB SSD drive.  The larger source has 2 partitions which I've shrunk the 1st main partition down so the total size of both partition will fit.  But the 2nd partition if restored in the same location would extend beyond the 256GB size.  There is a large gap between part 1 and 2.  The 2nd part is the boot part.  Will Clonzilla remove the gap or will it mess up if I use the -icds option?  What about the -k1 option (create the partition table proportionally) but that seems only for going to larger disks. Or could I restore each partition one at a time?  I've made a disk image so far.

I guess I could use gparted to "move" the part but in my experience gparted corrupts NTFS drives 50% of the time.

Thanks

Comment: Create two approprate partitons manually on the SSD. Then clone each partition onto those newly created partitons one at a time. Using "Paragon Free" or "Acronis" will achive this. Cloneing a 200gb drive with 50gb of data with either of those programs will result in a 50gb image file (use 3rd hard disk write the image there, or possibly on the fly if lack 3rd disk). That is to say the size of the target or destination partiton becomes irrelivent. Both programs should recreate boot flags on the appropriate partition, you "could" consider moving the bootable partition to be the first partition.

Comment: I used the restore parts instead of restore disk and selected both parts.  It got rid of the gap but it forgot to mark the 2nd part as bootable.  I can fix that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Clonezilla won't clone to a smaller disk](https://superuser.com/questions/1361361/clonezilla-wont-clone-to-a-smaller-disk)